# Ubuntu usb to vga screen driver

Tags: drivers, usb, multiple-monitors

I just bought usb to vga adpater and after installing drivers(from cd) for windows all looks nice. But I would like to do the same for my ubuntu.

These drivers for windows are "Thin2000 usb display adapter"
Adapter is usb 3.0 and I think it is supporting 2.0 also

```
Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
AMD A10-5745M APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics × 4 
Gallium 0.4 on AMD ARUBA (DRM 2.43.0, LLVM 3.8.0)
64-bit
```

Is there way to find any divers and install them for ubuntu? because frescologic isn't supporting linux

https://support.zoho.com/portal/frescologic/helpcenter/articles/operating-systems-supported

Will displaylink work for me?

logs from **lsusb**

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0bda:58c2 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0cf3:0036 Atheros Communications, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 008 Device 002: ID 1d5c:2000  
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: The output of `lsusb` should be useful in this case.

Comment: @mikewhatever I connected the adapter and updated main post with logs

Comment: Thanks. The deice in question is `1d5c:2000`, and a quick search shows nothing great so far. Looks like there is no working driver (let alone many), and no one has been able to get the device working.

Comment: Thanks. So what should I do next? Buy new usb to vga adapter?

Answer (score 1):

This probably isn't going to be what you want to hear, but most of the drivers for the USB to VGA adapters are designed for windows and not Linux systems.  Over the past month, I have been on a quest to add an additional monitor to my desktop (ubuntu 16.04 LTS).  I started with USB to VGA adapters, but I could not find one with a driver that was Linux-compatible, and I did a considerable amount of research trying to find one that was.

What ended up being the best option (really the only option, and relatively easy/cost effective) was buying a new graphics card (my original VGA port was just hard-wired) and a VGA-DVI adapter for the second monitor.

Sorry that this isn't much help in your current situation, but I have done a lot of looking and a lot of reading on other forums, and the general consensus is that USB to VGA is a pretty bad option for Linux.