# VGA to HDMI adapter drivers?

Tags: 16.04, multiple-monitors, screen, hdmi, lts

I'm trying to connect my second screen to my laptop.

I bought USB to VGA adapter but I can't make it work ([Ubuntu usb to vga screen driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/838467/ubuntu-usb-to-vga-screen-driver?noredirect=1#comment1282297_838467)).

If I buy VGA to HDMI adapter, will it work? (And is this solution dependent on my video card or something?)
Or what I have to do to have my second screen functional?

Comment: I had one of those in 2014 and it seems to me I had to run a 'mode' command and 'randr' command or something like that. On phone so can't link you anything for a 5 hours.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix that would be great if we could solve this issue

Comment: *If I could copy paste your solution

Comment: I'll be home soon and dig out the old laptop and old adapter and walk through installation steps. It may be different adapter than yours but I'll post everything in an answer in a couple of hours.

Answer (score 4):

Vga to hdmi adapters are just that; vga to hdmi adapters. they work without drivers. Therefore if your adapter is not outputting video when you connect a moniter then you might have a bad adapter. make sure that your second display is not shown in displays before coming to this conclusion

Comment: Well, sometimes the adapter doesn't support EDID well enough so you have to configure Modelines properly for your screen.

Answer (score 1):

I found the old VGA In+Audio In to HDMI Out adapter from 2014. It's a Foscom. On one side is 15-pin VGA and 3 pin Audio jack. On the other side is DC Power in, VGA Out and two LEDs, one red and one green.

Unfortunately I couldn't find the power adapter for it. I found old code which used to run in `/etc/rc.local` but was then moved to a script file to be called from `Startup Applications`:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#======== Call TV mode awhile after booting because it doesn't work on initial boot.
#
# This was copied from /etc/rc.local.  Annotations here should be replicated there.
# This script is used to plug VGA cable & audio into HDMI converter box.

# ---Outputs from "gtf" and "cvt" --------------------------------------------------------

#~$ gtf 1920 1080 60

#  # 1920x1080 @ 60.00 Hz (GTF) hsync: 67.08 kHz; pclk: 172.80 MHz
#  Modeline "1920x1080_60.00"  172.80  1920 2040 2248 2576  1080 1081 1084 1118  -HSync +Vsync

#~$ cvt 1920 1080 60
## 1920x1080 59.96 Hz (CVT 2.07M9) hsync: 67.16 kHz; pclk: 173.00 MHz
#Modeline "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


# Generate 1920x1080 using gtf instead of cvt
xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  172.80  1920 2040 2248 2576  1080 1081 1084 1118  -HSync +Vsync
xrandr --addmode VGA1 1920x1080_60.00
xrandr --output VGA1 --mode 1920x1080_60.00

exit 0
```

The # comments in the script indicate you need to run `gtf` (or `cvt`) passing the parameters 1920x1080 @ 60Hz to get thew `newmode` variables.

The `newmode` variables you right down and in turn type in to passs to xrandr `--newmode` parameter along with the variables you wrote down.

Note that your variables would be differen than mine unless you have a Toshiba Satellite Core 2 Duo T5750 laptop.

Sorry I was hoping to have a great answer but until I find the power supply for the Foscom VGA to HDMI converter I'm going by memory.

Comment: I recently bought a Mini VGA2HDMI adapter and had and issue with mode detection. Monitor connected using HDMI properly returned EDID information but when using VGA and adapter it didn't work so maximum resolution was 1024x768. @WinEunuuchs2Unix I used your script but instead of calculating the parameters with GTF or CVT I used what the screen was returning when connected directly. A tool called read-edid was very helpful.