# External monitor visual noise on LTS 18.04

Tags: xorg, multiple-monitors, intel-graphics, hdmi, display-resolution

I am on Ubuntu LTS 18.04. I am using a Lenovo Yoga 920, i7 / 16gb. Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (rev 07). The laptop screen is 4k.

When I connect my external monitor (usb-c to hdmi cable) and have it set to it's native resolution (1680x1050) [the screen has small specs of noise moving across it in a repetitive pattern](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3qBV.jpg). It also loses connection and re-establishes sporadically, maybe every minute, but sometimes longer. No screen tearing or other common issues I have seen searching online.

However, if I lower the resolution, it works fine. No problems at all.

I have tried using Wayland at login, but that did not help. And, I tried updating X from ppa, but I don't know if I did that correctly.

I did not try much else because I couldn't find any posts online with the same issue.

Can anyone help me resolve this? Let me know if any more information is needed and I will provide it promptly.

Comment: Rather than lowering the resolution try lowering the refresh rate a little bit a time until the problem goes away. Not an exact example but close one: https://askubuntu.com/questions/838892/vga-to-hdmi-adapter-drivers/838994#838994

Comment: As far as I can tell lowering the refresh rate does nothing. I don't know if it's not letting me change it because there is only one option, or if it has no effect. It doesn't return any error if I use `xrandr --output DP-1 --mode 1680x1050 --rate 50.00` or lower rates. When listing the display this is what it shows: `DP-1 connected 1680x1050+3840+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 465mm x 261mm
   1680x1050     59.95*+
   1920x1080     60.00    60.00    50.00    50.00    59.94  
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94 ` and so on with lower resolutions, couldn't fit it all here

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I see your post talks about adding new modes and maybe that is what I'm missing instead of just entering the xrandr command that I did, but unfortunately it's over my head right now and I don't understand it. I will keep trying though.